# How to protect Linux server from accidental file deletion

Tags: linux, server

Like a week ago a run this command on my server `mv /* ..` I was trying to move all the files from my current directory to the parent directory but ended up screwing all my server :)

Is there a way to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: No, since you have root permissions

Comment: Try setting up a user with limited/restricted permissions. You could also setup aliases for the commands you are afraid of and have them do somthing else, for example run a script that says "Are you sure?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend using a minimalistic file-manager like midnight-commander to transfer files.

However the answer to your question is **no**, if you're working with root permissions you have all abilities to destroy your system.

> With great power comes great responsibility - Benjamin Franklin Parker known as Uncle Ben

you can limit the access rights by using a different user than root.

Comment: Ok but that quote is attributed to the Uncle Ben not Peter

Comment: you are right, thanks for clearing this up. I am happy to see that some people know the details.

Answer (score 1):

Backups!!!

As mentioned by Chris, you can setup a system with user permissions, group permissions, .... In top of this, I have the impression that you missed a dot: `mv ./...` instead of `mv /...` (I hope you did not set root directory `/` as your home directory? In case you did, change this immediately).

But most of all: regular backups!!! UNIX/Linux doesn't have a system restore, as Windows has, nor is there a recycle bin. Therefore, regular backups (to another machine, obviously) are a must.